# How do I make the background image still while scrolling?

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner in html and CSS I was trying to modify my old project by adding a background image and I want the image to take the size of screen while remaining still while I scroll up or down
here is my code

'''

```
body {
  background-image:    url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/3WHvvnFSspZKbbRkM9SgvIUMDs6efWS5vXgmSglvoHASfV4TUhIFSXd77Ic9x02zAmyrMwpg-py0YceJYVLLCK9SpU9YQU56rm-uTBKb2KoTW3dnjpgVLvhJ26koIF-VXlzao11v=w2400);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

h1, h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.catphoto {
  text-align : center;
}
```

'''

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please also add your HTML code to this question, or it is much harder to help you. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the `background-attachment` property in CSS.

Example:

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1080/1920);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  
  background-attachment: fixed;
  
  height: 300vh;
}

.cover {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 50vh;
  margin-top: 90vh;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
  (covering up so you can see the effect)
</div>
```

This fixes the position of the background to a specific place, like an element with the `position` of it set to `fixed`. It can easily be ported to your code by adding a single line in the CSS.

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

More information about `background-attachment`: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment) [web.dev](https://web.dev/learn/css/backgrounds/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and but can you please tell me the use of .cover selector

Comment: `.cover` is not a selector, it is an element, and I used the class name to change the styling of it. I used the element to cover up the background to show the effect of it, as you can see in the preview. It is not required in your implementation of it.

Comment: oh I wrote selector in confusion you helped me clear that up but I meant that is .cover and empty to in html?

Comment: I don't understand, but all the code you need is in body in CSS (minus the height). The cover part is only there just so you can see the effect while scrolling.

Comment: ohh ohk I got it now thanks